# New internal ext4 HDD not showing up

Tags: boot, mount, hard-drive

I have a new Dell Inspiron 3501 with SSD that I set up to dual boot Ubuntu 20.10 and Windows.
I just found out the laptop has an HDD slot ready, and I happened to have an ext4 formatted 1TB drive that I used as external drive through a docking station, so I threw it in to format it as NTFS and use it to swap files.

But neither Ubuntu nor Windows see the drive. It appears correctly in BIOS and I can hear it spinning, so power and cable are good.
Also booting time is significantly increased, so something is happening there.

`sudo fdisk -l` does not show it, neither is it anywhere in `/dev/`

In Windows as well nothing happens, I was expecting the usual message asking to format the drive as it is an unsupported file system...

I need to access the drive before formatting to transfer the files currently on it. I know I could just remove it and do all this from usb but it's strange that the drive is simply not seen.

Any idea of the reason, and possible solutions?
Thank you!

Edit: Here is the output of `sudo lsblk`. Still nothing.
[sudo lsblk output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrbq5.png)

Comment: Can you update your question to include the output of `sudo lsblk`? This will show all devices and partitions that your computer is aware of, including the ones that are not mounted or immediately visible.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the output of `lsblk`, one can safely say that both Ubuntu and Windows are correct: you do not have another hard drive installed on that computer. That said, many years of supporting people with Dell devices leads to the following *probable* solutions ... though your mileage may vary.

First, let's review the report regarding the hard drive that you provided:

1. This was at one time used in an external dock
2. You can hear it spin
3. You can see the drive in your BIOS
4. Booting the computer in either operating system is sluggish

If you can hear it spin, this is a good indicator that the drive is receiving power, but not much else. Your boot partitions for both Ubuntu and Windows are on an NVMe device, so the systems should load in the same amount of time regardless of whether you have a spinning disk installed or not. However, the fact that it's taking longer leads me to believe you have one of two problems:

1. The hard drive is not properly seated in the HDD bay
   ⇢ A loose hard drive might have enough of a connection for power, but the data lines of the SATA connection may not be completely seated. Confirm the hard drive is properly mounted and screwed into place.
2. The hard drive is damaged
   ⇢ Just because a disk spins does not mean it's any good.

The fact that booting the system takes noticeably longer means the computer — and the operating systems — are trying to access the device that is reported by your BIOS and failing each time. This can be caused by a number of things. Your best bet would be to use the built-in disk diagnostics that ship with Dell notebooks to test the device.

Here's how you can do it:

1. Restart your notebook
2. When the Dell logo appears, press <kbd>F12</kbd> key to enter the "One-time Boot Menu"
3. Use the arrow keys to select "Diagnostics" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Follow the on-screen prompts to test your hard drive

If the disk is bad, the system will let you know.

Comment: Thank you @Matigo for your suggestions, I tried all but no result: disk is firmly in place but even diagnostics doesn't pick it up. I ended up taking it out and plugging it back in the docking station, where it works perfectly. Formatted it in NTFS and popped it back in, same situation, it only appears in BIOS.
I'm wondering whether it's a matter of compatibility: the disk was manufactured in 2015, could it be too old?